# Sorting each case-when statements

Tags: sql

Here is my users DB :

```
id | sex    | trending | date_registered
---+--------+----------+----------------
1  | male   | 1        | 29-04-2020
2  | male   | 1        | 28-04-2020
3  | male   | 0        | 27-04-2020
4  | female | 1        | 26-04-2020
5  | female | 1        | 25-04-2020
6  | female | 0        | 24-04-2020
7  | female | 0        | 23-04-2020
8  | male   | 1        | 22-04-2020
9  | male   | 0        | 21-04-2020
```

I use the following querie in order to return :

(1) Trending females

(2) Rest of females

(3) Trending males

(4) Rest of males

```
select
    id,
    sex,
    trending,
    date_registered
from users
order by
    case
        when sex = 'female' and trending = 1 then 1
        when sex = 'female' and trending = 0 then 2
        when sex = 'male' and trending = 1 then 3
        when sex = 'male' and trending = 0 then 4
    end
```

[here is the demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ras19AoGdPbKHGcQMZati/0)

What I want on top of that is sorting by the most recent users first for each case-when statements.

For example `when sex = 'female' and trending = 1 then 1` returns a ASC sorting, so the oldest users will be shown first.

When I try a DESC sorting on the case-when statements like bellow, it doesn't change anything :

```
order by
(CASE when sex = 'female' and trending = 1 then 1 END) DESC,
(CASE when sex = 'female' and trending = 0 then 2 END) DESC,
(CASE when sex = 'male' and trending = 1 then 3 END) DESC,
(CASE when sex = 'male' and trending = 0 then 4 END) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a fiddle, it made answering the question much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirements, you need to sort by `sex` ascending (so that females are first), `trending` descending (so that trending users are first) and `date_registered` descending (so that most recent users are first):

```
select
    id,
    sex,
    trending,
    date_registered
from users
order by sex, trending desc, date_registered desc
```

Output for your fiddle:

```
id  sex     trending    date_registered
4   female  1           26-04-2020
5   female  1           25-04-2020
6   female  0           24-04-2020
7   female  0           23-04-2020
1   male    1           29-04-2020
2   male    1           28-04-2020
8   male    1           22-04-2020
3   male    0           27-04-2020
9   male    0           21-04-2020
```

[Updated demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ras19AoGdPbKHGcQMZati/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write this as:

```
order by sex, trending desc
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ras19AoGdPbKHGcQMZati/0) is your db<>fiddle.

Comment: it would not return the data in the order I want

Comment: @casusbelli . . . Once I fixed the column names, it does in fact return the data in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put DESC only after CASE block(After END keyword):

```
select
    id,
    sex,
    trending,
    date_registered
from users
order by
    case
        when sex = 'female' and trending = 1 then 1
        when sex = 'female' and trending = 0 then 2
        when sex = 'male' and trending = 1 then 3
        when sex = 'male' and trending = 0 then 4
    end DESC
```

Comment: it returns the males first